# Cascade INSERT using SEQUENCE - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to copy records from two tables and re-insert them once again into these tables with only one field different (PK for parent table, PK and FK for child table). PK can be taken from SEQUENCE, the problem I am facing is how to cascade update the FK in the child table.

I have the following table **My_List**, where *Sup_ID* is Primary Key

**My_List**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Sup_ID | Sup_Name |  Sup_Code |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | AA       |        23 |
|      2 | BB       |        87 |
|      3 | CC       |        90 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

And the following table **My_List_details**, where *Buy_ID* is Primary Key (taken from SEQUENCE, assumed already created) and *Sup_ID* is Foreign Key points at *My_List.Sup_ID*

**My_List_details**

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
| Buy_ID | Sup_ID | Sup_Detail | Max_Amount | Min_Amount |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
|     33 |      1 | AAA        |          1 |         10 |
|     34 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     35 |      3 | CCC        |         21 |         30 |
|     36 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

**---------------------------------------------------**

***Objectives***

Write PL/SQL Function does the following:

1. Copy *My_List* records and re-insert then with the new PK -> *Sup_ID* values taken from SEQUENCE.
2. Copy *My_List_details* records and re-insert them with the new *Sup_ID* foreign key according My_List.Sup_ID, and Buy_ID from SEQUENCE.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

***Expected Outcome***

**My_List**

```
+--------+----------+----------+
| Sup_ID | Sup_Name | Sup_Code |
+--------+----------+----------+
|      1 | AA       |       23 |
|      2 | BB       |       87 |
|      3 | CC       |       90 |
|      4 | AA       |       23 |
|      5 | BB       |       87 |
|      6 | CC       |       90 |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

**My_List_details**

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
| Buy_ID | Sup_ID | Sub_Detail | Max_Amount | Min_Amount |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
|     33 |      1 | AAA        |          1 |         10 |
|     34 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     35 |      3 | CCC        |         21 |         30 |
|     36 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     37 |      1 | AAA        |          1 |         10 |
|     38 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
|     39 |      3 | CCC        |         21 |         30 |
|     40 |      2 | BBB        |         11 |         20 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I have started with is the following:

```
BEGIN
    FOR   d  IN (
                    SELECT  Sup_Name, Sup_Code
                    FROM    My_List
                )
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO MY_List SELECT Sup_ID.NEXTVAL, Sup_Name, Sup_Code 
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

However, I am not sure about the following:

- How to replace FK in My_List_Details with the new values of PK in My_List. My_List_Detail
- Extend the function to update any number of child tables (Cascade update), (e.g. FK for five tables point to PK of My_List, need to be updated in the same manner).

Comment: You can either use `returning into` clause of the `insert` statement to get just inserted value of `sup_id` column or reference `sequence_name.currval` to get the current value of the sequence.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Sup_id in My_List_details is FK, so it's repeated randomly more than once. I could not find that *returning into* would replace each old FK with the new one. I updated the second table to reflect this trait.

Comment: Do you try to implement history of changes?

Comment: @Franek I am not sure if I got what you mean, but basically I try to insert another copy of My_List table records to the same table. Of course, this needs to be inserted with different PK values. Therefore, all dependent FK values need to be updated as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solves my problem (given that sup_seq and buy_seq are two created SEQUENCES):

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cOld IS
      SELECT *
      FROM my_list;

   new_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR rOld IN cOld LOOP
      new_id := sup_seq.NEXTVAL;  -- Get the ID to use for the new row

      INSERT INTO my_list
             (sup_id,sup_name,sup_code)
      VALUES (new_id,rOld.sup_name,rOld.sup_code);

      INSERT INTO my_list_details
            (buy_id,sup_id,sup_detail,max_amount,min_amount)
      SELECT buy_seq.NEXTVAL,new_id,sup_detail,max_amount,min_amount
      FROM   my_list_details
      WHERE  sup_id = rOld.sup_id;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Althugh using a cursor might not be recommended if the problem can be solved in other way, for me I found it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think good solution would be extend all primary keys by additional column which will be incremented by trigger when cloning records occure.
Let's call this additional column SEC_ID. SEC_ID should by incremented and used in context of only one primary key.
You don't have to create as many sequences as SEC_ID columns in tables. You can query in trigger for last sec_id for your ID and then increment it to insert in new valid primary key with original id.

Advantages:

simple mechanism

simple extending for new tables

Comment: I understand, but how to map PK to FK's in the newly inserted records in My_List_Details table. The relationship between My_list and My_list_details is 1..*, hence, FK's of My_List_Details do not follow the same number and order of My_List's PK's